# I am unable to copy my NSMutable array to appDelegate_iPhone array(Universal app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Actually I have parsed an XML and store URL's of images as an `NSMutableArray` object, but I want this array to be used in another `ViewController` (to give to `UIImage` in `UIImageView` to show Images at runtime), so I am trying to **copy that Mutable array** to `myAppDelegate_iPhone's NSMutableArray`. And I want to **again copy that Appdelegate's array** to my next or other `ViewControllers` `NSMutableArray`.

so can anyone help me out **pleaseeeeee**? Here is my code :-

code:-

```
@class FirstViewController;

@interface AppDelegate_iPhone : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;

    FirstViewController *viewController;

    NSMutableArray *logoArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *logoArray;

@end



#import "AppDelegate_iPhone.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "ParsingViewController.h"


@implementation AppDelegate_iPhone

@synthesize window,logoArray;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;


    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://litofinter.es.milfoil.arvixe.com/displayxml1.aspx"];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];



    //Initialize the delegate.
    ParsingViewController *parser = [[ParsingViewController alloc] init];

    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    logoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

// dealloc done

@end


@class Litofinter,AppDelegate_iPhone;

@interface ParsingViewController : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate> {

    NSString *myString;
    NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
    Litofinter *obj;
    NSString *currentElement;

    AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate;


}


#import "ParsingViewController.h"
#import "Litofinter.h"
#import "AppDelegate_iPhone.h"

@implementation ParsingViewController

@synthesize myMutableArray, myString;



-(id)init{
    if(self == [super init]){
        myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self; 
}




- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    //myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

// Parsing done here


- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


    //UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    //appDelegate=app.delegate;

    appDelegate.logoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:myMutableArray];

    NSLog(@"appDelegate.logoArray count %d",[appDelegate.logoArray count]);

    for (Litofinter *lito in appDelegate.logoArray) {
        NSLog(@"Array Elements :----- %@",lito.cLogo);
    }
}


@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AppDelegate_iPhone,Litofinter,ParsingViewController;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    NSMutableArray *array;
    //Litofinter *lito;
    NSString *logoString;
    AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate;

    ParsingViewController *obj;

}

@end



#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate_iPhone.h"
#import "Litofinter.h"

#import "ParsingViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

-(id)init{
    if(self == [super init]){
        obj = [[ParsingViewController alloc] init];
        array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: obj.myMutableArray];
    }
    return self; 
}
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int x=5,y=10;


    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


//  UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
//  appDelegate=app.delegate;

    NSLog(@"delegate Array ====== %d",[appDelegate.logoArray count]);
    NSLog(@"New Array ====== %d",[obj.myMutableArray count]);

/*
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:appDelegate.logoArray];

    NSLog(@"array at 0 ===== %@",[array objectAtIndex:0]);

    for (Litofinter *lito1 in obj.myMutableArray) {
        NSLog(@"Array Elements in Lito1 are :------------- %@",lito1.cLogo);
    }

    for (Litofinter *lito2 in array) {
        NSLog(@"Array Elements in Lito1 are :------------- %@",lito2.cLogo);
    }
*/

    for (Litofinter *lito in obj.myMutableArray) {

    //for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.logoArray count]; i++) {

    //  lito.cLogo = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",lito.cLogo);
        UIImage *imageFromUrl = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:lito.cLogo]];



        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageFromUrl];
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 196, 90)];
        [self.view addSubview:imgView];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTapImage)];
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
    //  [tgr release];

        //Do the rest of your operations here, don't forget to release the UIImageView
        x = x + 200;

    }


}


-(void)onTapImage
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message from mAc" message:@"Trail" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [alert show];
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Where is your code to copy  `appDelegate.logoArray` into an, local array...

Comment: Try this. `appDelegate.logoArray = [myMutableArray copy];`

Comment: guys copying part is done now, but i m getting SigAbort when i pass the url to the uiimage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
UIImage *imageFromUrl = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lito.cLogo]]];
```